# How to write text below every image in marquee slide show

Tags: html, css, slideshow, marquee

I want to write three lines of text below every image in this marquee slide-show.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranlanke/65Wf5/1/)

```
<marquee bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="5%" width="600px" direction="left" scrolldelay="120" align="middle" >
    <img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" width="120px" height="120px" border="5"/>
    <img src="http://www.pictures-of-cats.org/images/Pixiebob-cat-list-of-cat-breeds-pictures-of-cats.jpg" width="120px" height="120px" border="5"/>
    <img src="http://www.pictures-of-cats.org/images/ragdoll-cat-small-pictures-of-cats.jpg" height="120px" width="120px" border="5"/>
    <img src="http://www.pictures-of-cats.org/images/ragdoll-cat-small-pictures-of-cats.jpg" height="120px" width="120px" border="5" />
    <img src="http://www.pictures-of-cats.org/images/Pixiebob-cat-list-of-cat-breeds-pictures-of-cats.jpg" height="120px" width="120px" border="5" />
    <img src="http://www.pictures-of-cats.org/images/Pixiebob-cat-list-of-cat-breeds-pictures-of-cats.jpg" height="120px" width="120px" border="5" />
    <img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" height="120px" width="120px" border="5"/>
    <img src="Animal68.gif" height="120px" width="120px" border="5" />
    <img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" height="120px" width="120px" border="5" />
    <img src="http://www.pictures-of-cats.org/images/Pixiebob-cat-list-of-cat-breeds-pictures-of-cats.jpg" height="120px" width="120px" border="5" />
</marquee>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranlanke/65Wf5/1/

Comment: I want too, what did you tried ?

Comment: Was just about to ask the same.

Comment: Alos, you are using the `<marquee> element incorrectly: **The HTML <marquee> element is used to insert a scrolling area of TEXT** not images: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: Check this demo jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/65Wf5/3/

Comment: @Paulie_D: i need a slide show like this (marquee). There is any way to build a slide show like this (with out using marquee).....Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?:

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/65Wf5/2/)**

wrapping `img` tag with a `div` then style it like this: `.item { float:left}` (class *item* it is whatever you like, i just used here because that was the class used on the FIDDLE)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `<marquee>` for images! But if you need to, then you can use it this way: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65Wf5/4/)

```
<marquee bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="5%" width="600px" direction="left" scrolldelay="120" align="middle" >
    <div style="width:120px; display: inline-block">                    
        <img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" width="120px" height="120px" border="5"/>
        <div>Text</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:120px; display: inline-block">                    
        <img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" width="120px" height="120px" border="5"/>
        <div>Text</div>
    </div>
</marquee>
```